# Can't bind lvalue to rvalue in member function but ok in global function

Tags: c++, templates, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, member-functions

While looking at the reference pages for [std::forward](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/) I came across something odd. The example is passing an lvalue as an rvalue reference.. but to a global function... and it compiles and runs. I tried the same thing as a member function and it fails to compile. What gives? I would expect both calls to fail without the use of `std::move` or `std::forward<T>`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void globalDoSomething(T &&data) {
    std::cout << "We're doing it!!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    void doSomething(T &&data);
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::doSomething(T &&data)
{
    std::cerr << "Ah, man. I won't compile." << std::endl;
}

template class A<int>;

int main()
{

    int b = 0;
    globalDoSomething(b);

    A<int> a;
    a.doSomething(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the automatic template deduction for `globalDoSomething` infers `T` as `int&`.

If you explicitly instantiate the template function with `globalDoSomething<int>(b);` like you did for the member function of the template class, it will also fail to compile.

Conversely, if you instantiate the template class with `A<int&> a;`, it will successfully compile.

Comment: Ahhhh, well that makes perfect sense! Thank you for the quick answer. I have added templates to the question tags!

Comment: In other words, it's not actually an rvalue reference, but a so-called "forwarding reference" (or "universal reference" in older parlance). Though its magic is powered by pretty normal rules (as Patrick has pointed out), we tend to think of a `T&&` with template `T` as being its own special thing, because it's convenient to do so.

Answer (score 1):

To build/add on @Patrick Roberts answer, from [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

> If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter
> (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call
> argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place
> of A for deduction

In short, while `b` is an lvalue, it infers `T` as `int&` indeed. And as shown in the example

```
template<class T>
int f(T&& x) {                    // x is a forwarding reference
    return g(std::forward<T>(x)); // and so can be forwarded
}
 
int main() {
    int i;
    f(i); // argument is lvalue, calls f<int&>(int&), std::forward<int&>(x) is lvalue
}
```

---

To test this, you can set a few overloaded functions with different types and check

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


void f(int&& x) {
    std::cout << "rvalue reference overload f("  ")\n";
}

void f(const int& x) {
    std::cout << "lvalue reference to const overload f("  ")\n";
}

void f(int& x) {
    std::cout << "lvalue reference overload f("  ")\n";
}

template <typename T>
void globalDoSomething(T &&data) {
    f(data);
}

int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    globalDoSomething(b); 
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

> lvalue reference overload f()

Comment: There's an even easier test without defining a bunch of overloaded functions, by adding `static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int&>);` in the body of `globalDoSomething()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I simply pasted the [reference declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) example :)